# How to load a xls or csv data file to work with the rugarch and rmgarch packages in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and have just started to use it. I am currently experimenting with the quantmod, rugarch and rmgarch packages.

In particular, I'm implementing the last package to make a multivariate portfolio analysis for the case of the european markets. In this sense, I need to download the 3-month german treasury bills, in order to use them as risk free rate. However, as far as I known, I can´t download the the mentioned data serie from Yahoo, Google or FDRA databases, so I have already downloaded them from investing.com and I want to load them in R.

The fact here is, my data is different from the ones downloaded by the getsymbols () function of yahoo, because in this case I only have 2 columns, the date column and the closing price column. To sump up, the question arises here is, is there any way to load this type of data in R for rmgarch purposes??

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand -- what's the issue with the Yahoo data? You can load a CSV by using `my_data <- read.csv(file="TheDataIWantToReadIn.csv")`

Comment: The problem is that I have not found treasury bills data in Yahoo. This is why I want to load a csv or xls with my own data (previously downloaded in investing). In this way, if I use the read.csv to load the data, then the rmgarch fucntions such as dccfit don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the issue, but this is how you might go about getting the data from a csv file.

```
data <- read.csv(file="file/path/data.csv")
head(data)  # Take a look at your data

# Do this if you want the data only replacing ColumnName with the proper name
data_only <- data$ColumnName
```

It looks like the input data for rugarch needs to be an xts vector. So, you might want to take a look at [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/r-xts-cheat-sheet). You might also want to take a look at `?read.csv`.

Comment: thank you very much. I have already solved the problem, the key was the xts format.